# Increasing water temperature in water heater

Tags: water, heater

What advantages do you get by increasing water temp on dual thermostat water heater?

Comment: It's a trade-off: hotter water is better for washing, particularly dish washers, but is dangerous (accidental scalds), shortens the heater life and costs more.

Comment: is this a question about `dual thermostat water heater` or is it about `any water heater`?

Answer (score 3):

Advantage: you keep [Legionella bacteria](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/turning-water-heater-up-kill-bacteria-54596.html) from harming your family.

Disadvantage: risk of scalding at any temperature that will kill Legionella

Go with automatic anti-scald blending faucets, and you get the best of both worlds and longer showers too.